# rails console fails to find installed gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

```
$ bundle install |grep chunk
Using chunky_png 1.3.3
$ rails c
Could not find chunky_png-1.3.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I've tried removing all gems from the rvm gemset and re-running bundle twice, doesn't help. Any ideas?

This is on an Ubuntu 13.10 machine. Same code base on my Mac OSX machine works fine.

Comment: check this out [Gem issues with rake tasks and bundle install](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/152)

Comment: Problem referenced there involves zsh/bash rbenv/rvm, I am just using bash and rvm.

Comment: try bundle exec rails c

Comment: Tried that too, no change.

Comment: Check your rvm setup: `type rvm | head -n 1` Should be `rvm is a function`

Answer (score 2):

Usually, this happens because Bundler and Rails are running with different versions of Ruby. To check, run `bundle env` and `rails runner 'puts RUBY_VERSION'`.

If that doesn't solve it, please add the output of both to your question.

Comment: The problem somehow went away, perhaps after a reboot.  If it pops up again I will try this, thanks.