# Why isn't Rails able to find my installed gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm working with the Dropbox SDK and have included `gem 'dropbox-sdk','~> 1.6.4'` in my Gemfile, and I've run `bundle install`. I've verified that it's getting installed by running `bundle show dropbox-sdk` which shows it as installed in `/Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2/gems/dropbox-sdk-1.6.4`.

The problem is that my pages are throwing up file not found errors, and I'm not able to require it in the console.

Console error:

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
2.2.0 :001 > require 'dropbox-sdk'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- dropbox-sdk
```

Page error:

```
LoadError in DashboardsController#monthly_sales_dashboard
No such file to load -- dropbox-sdk

Extracted source (around line #274):

  def require(file)
    result = false
    load_dependency(file) { result = super }
    result
  end
end
```

The weirdest part is that it was working a little while ago and I haven't changed any configs or gems since then.

I've tried restarting Thin and even restarting the whole computer, but no luck. I checked that Bundler and Rails are on the same version per [Tim Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26857503/710709)'s answer in a similar question and they're both running off of 2.2.0.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the exact error message you are seeing?

Comment: Updated question with actual messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the gem is named with a dash, when requiring the gem you must use an underscore:

```
require 'drobbox_sdk'
```

Comment: And just like that... Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Further to infused's answer, you can load the dependency without needing the explicit `require` in your code by specifying the name to require in your Gemfile. Just replace `gem 'dropbox-sdk'` with:

```
gem 'dropbox-sdk', require: 'dropbox_sdk'
```

and it will behave like all your other dependencies.